# Visual Studio Quick Keys Captured by Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-express

I have installed Visual Studio Express 2015 on Windows 7 and am using it for C++ 11 development.

I would like to set break points and can do it with the menu by going to Debug:"Toggle Breakpoint".  However I should be able to click on the the location, where I want the breakpoint, and hit F9.  However, when I do click F9, the control panel window comes up instead of my getting the breakpoint.  Is there a way to make VS quick keys take precedence over Windows 7 quick keys?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Windows 7, but I'm almost certain that F9 isn't a Windows shortcut for the Control Panel, are you using a keyboard that has an Fn or "F Lock" key (i.e. the function keys all do various Windows shortcuts unless the Fn key is also pressed or the F Lock key is active)?  Or are you using AutoHotkey or some other keyboard shortcut augmenting software?

Comment: That's it!  I have a Lenovo laptop and I had switched the Fn and Ctrl keys (using BIOS) since the Lenovo laptops, I have seen, put the Fn key where most keyboards put the Ctrl key.  Fn-F9 gives me the breakpoint as (I have since found) does clicking on the far left (usually a light blue strip) of the code window.  Thanks very much,